How to convert variable length datetime column to datetime dtype in pandas dataframe
I have a column of data that is formatted as XXh:XXm:XXs but the hours/minutes/seconds can be different lengths depending on their values
Example:
123h:23m:1s
1h:1m:1s
12h:0m:14s
How can I convert a column to datetime with these variable lengths.
I have tried:
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='HHh:MMm:SSs')

But it fails on the first row that doesn't match that specific length for HH, MM, SS exactly.

In the future, please provide a [mre]. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples. In this case the input could be as simple as s = pd.Series(['123h:23m:1s', '1h:1m:1s', '12h:0m:14s']). It's not clear what output you were expecting, but the linked answer should clear that up.
